# Function offsets in the executable file

Tags: windows, exe, executable, portable-executable

Having a compiled file (an `exe`), for e.g. for such a simple c++ program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

    void my_int_func(int x) {
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
    
    int main() {
    
        void (*foo)(int);
        foo = &my_int_func;
    
        foo(78);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

am I right that the function offsets are always fixed and written into the `PE`? I'm asking that because i have some 3-rd party program that works on some `exe` file and utilizes the function offsets as constant, fixed values.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

> am I right that the function offsets are always fixed and written into the PE?

Yes, once compiled the executable binary doesn't change, so the offsets, RVA (Relative Virtual Address) and VA (Virtual Address) always stay the same. (note, suggested by Sourena : VA is subject to [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) which is per-boot on Windows; so basically is stays the same as long as you don't reboot).

Be wary that if you recompile the code, the resulting binary might be completely different (that is, the functions, global variables, and pretty much everything might be located at completely different addresses) for the same source code.

For a completely different source code, the resulting binary will be completely different.

All in all if your tool targets a specific version, it's possible to use hardcoded offsets, but once the the program is recompiled (or moreover changed) then the tool **will** definitely fail.

Comment: If `my_int_func` is external to the module (say, an imported function), then its offset will change at runtime.

Comment: @Neitsa, the VA is not always the same. VA is based on the ImageBase value and it's always the same in a PE file, but there is no guarantee that the operating system loads the PE file in the exact same address as specified in the ImageBase (because of ASLR). Therefore, you can only count on RVA not VA.

Comment: @Sourena Yes you're right, that's a precision that I should have made; In my mind, the VA stays constant "per boot", but if you don't know that Windows' ASLR is per-boot, this can clearly be misleading.